# Is this the picture of a renormalization group flow?

Tags: renormalization

Please look at the cover of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/272960197X) written by Le Bellac.
the book

I guess that the picture is about a renormalization group flow (the arrows on the lines).
i found a similar picture [here](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiXx-vB16DmAhXKyIUKHb19DsgQFjAAegQIAhAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fguava.physics.uiuc.edu%2F~nigel%2Fcourses%2F563%2FEssays_2017%2FPDF%2Fdubinkin_version_2.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3YpMC0UBGSkCkGdgaoOUmm) here . Look at figure 1.the model is the sine Gordon model. the x axis is the number of dimensions so it starts ar d = 1.
It does not seem to be the case on the cover. 
Could you comment it?
thanks.

Comment: While there is single picture for RG flow, many different models can (and do) share similar behaviors. The picture on the cover of the book seems like the flow of the coupling coefficients in the Kondo model, where the $x$-axis is $J_z$ and the $y$-axis is $J_\perp$. For example see here: http://tqm.courses.phy.cam.ac.uk/docs/lectures/KondoEffect/

Comment: In the last figure of the link, is the 0 point on the x axis a critical point? (I ask the question because there is a repulsive arrow on the right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the RG flow pictured on the cover of Le Bellac is probably showing the famous [Kosterlitz RG flow for the XY model](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0022-3719/7/6/005), which itself is dual to the sine-Gordon model. And as mentioned in the comments, there are other systems inequivalent to these which have the same RG flow (the most famous of which is likely the anisotropic Kondo RG flow obtained by [Anderson, Yuval, Hamann](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.1.4464)).

> Look at figure 1.the model is the sine Gordon model. the x axis is the number of dimensions so it starts ar d = 1. It does not seem to be the case on the cover. Could you comment it? thanks.

The "dimension" used for the $x$-axis in the link is the *scaling dimension* of a particular operator, which is distinct from the spacetime dimension of the system in question. The paper you have linked works entirely in $(1+1)$ spacetime dimensions, while the scaling dimension of the operator may be tuned continuously with the couplings in the model of interest. Therefore, variable on the x-axis is equivalent to a parametrization of a coupling in the sine-Gordon model.